# Count a 2D array within a range

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I have a map that I want to separately count the patterns of different numbers.

[image: Image Map]

Without VB, I want to be able to create a dynamic counter that will be able to count the patterns of numbers.

For example:

I want to count how many times, even if it overlaps that this pattern occurs in the map

```
2 2
2 2
```

Counting I can see the pattern occurs six times but I'm struggling to create a simple array formula that will be able to do so

I've been told of success with and IF function with nested AND functions so I know it can be done without VB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:E15,2,B1:F15,2)
```

notice how the two areas are adjacent - one column offset from each other.

[image]

You can extend this to find two-by-two regions:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:E14,2,B1:F14,2,A2:E15,2,B2:F15,2)
```

just be very careful about how the different ranges are offset.

An alternative way to write this which, I suspect, will be more efficient for large ranges is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E14=2)*(B1:F14=2)*(A2:E15=2)*(B2:F15=2))
```

Comment: That's a clever use of `COUNTIFS`. I came up with something much more convoluted.

Comment: Thank you @DougGlancy. Yes, I think it could be done with something more complicated, perhaps OFFSET(), maybe an array formula. I might explore this - just for the challenge ;)

Comment: Well, there is this array formula `=SUM(IF($A$1:$E$14=2,IF($B$1:$F$14=2,IF($A$2:$E$15=2,IF($B$2:$F$15=2,1,0),0),0),0))` but the SUMPRODUCT is much easier, and is doing the same thing.

Comment: Hi Andy, that is great. I thought I had already attempted that. Thanks so much!